# javascript remove last class assigned OR replace last class with new class

Tags: javascript

```
let addDarkColor = ["darkAqua","darkPurple","darkGreen", "darkYellow", "darkOrange", "darkRed", "darkPink"];
```

Here is an array of my classes I want to replace per time it's ran

```
questionContainer.classList.add(addDarkColor[nextClicked])
```

This is what I currently have, just adding on a new class everytime, however, it stacks, obviously. It's working, but at the same time, I didn't want my questionContainer to have stacked classes like : "darkAqua","darkPurple","darkGreen", "darkYellow" everytime it is clicked. Is there a way to either remove the last class assigned to it before adding the class (so I dont have to specify each time WHAT class is being removed, just the last one assigned) Or preferebly, replace the last assigned class with my new class. 
I could not find an answer anywhere that wasn't JQuery. I do not know or have qjuery installed, so please help with vanilla Javascript

Comment: Do you loop when it reaches the end?

Comment: No, it ends and that container becomes display: "none" and it shows the results of the test after. However, it will probably have a button of sorts that restarts the test to try again that re-shows the container again from the start with its started styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also reference the previous class and remove it

```js
let addDarkColor = ["darkAqua","darkPurple","darkGreen", "darkYellow", "darkOrange", "darkRed", "darkPink"];

var questionContainer = document.querySelector(".test")
var nextClicked = 0
function next() {

  var prev = nextClicked - 1
  if (prev < 0) {
    prev = addDarkColor.length - 1
  }
  
  questionContainer.classList
    .add(addDarkColor[nextClicked])
  questionContainer.classList
    .remove(addDarkColor[prev])
  
  nextClicked++
  if (nextClicked >= addDarkColor.length) nextClicked = 0
}

questionContainer.addEventListener("click", next)
next()
```

```css
.darkAqua { background-color: aqua }
.darkPurple  { background-color: purple }
.darkGreen  { background-color: green }
.darkYellow  { background-color: yellow }
.darkOrange  { background-color: orange }
.darkRed  { background-color: red }
.darkPink  { background-color: pink }
```

```html
<div class="test">Hello</div>
```

If you do not know what class it is, you can remove all the classes.

```
questionContainer.classList
  .remove(addDarkColor.join(' '))
questionContainer.classList
  .add(addDarkColor[nextClicked])
```

Comment: Wow thanks!! You did it so very fast haha I feel so stupid. I had been trying to figure it out fo a while and soon thing I posted this, I realized something I could do haha But I used your code, it works! Thank you!!